# How to export ALL current data from Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

By default, the Grid exports its current data. That means it exports only data that are shown in table and not all of them. I have read the documentation [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/#toc-exporting-specific-data) and I managed to export all data but every time I filter the table still exports all the data.
My code:

```
contructor() {this.allData = this.allData.bind(this);}

public allData(): ExcelExportData {
const result: ExcelExportData = {
  data: this.ciConfig
};
return result;
```

HTML:

```
<kendo-grid-excel fileName="CustomerInfo_Configuration.xlsx" [fetchData]="allData"></kendo-grid-excel>
```

I think I need to use "process()" like shown in documentation in order to set the current total in "this.ciConfig" but I cannot figure it out.

Any help how to export all data (not only the showed page)?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following:-

- Use a variable state to store the current filter and sort.
- Then on data change capture the grid data result.
- Then on process pass the state but set the page size to total records captured by grid data result.
  Please refer to the snippet below which uses State, GridDataResult and process() to export in the grid.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { process, State } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { sampleProducts } from './products';
import { ExcelExportData } from '@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export';

import {
    GridComponent,
    GridDataResult,
    DataStateChangeEvent
} from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <kendo-grid
        [data]="gridData"
        [pageSize]="state.take"
        [skip]="state.skip"
        [sort]="state.sort"
        [filter]="state.filter"
        [sortable]="true"
        [pageable]="true"
        filterable="menu"
        (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)">
    <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
                <button type="button" kendoGridExcelCommand icon="file-excel">Export to Excel</button>
    </ng-template>
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40" [filterable]="false">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="FirstOrderedOn" title="First Ordered On" width="240" filter="date" format="{0:d}">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" width="180" filter="numeric" format="{0:c}">
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" width="120" filter="boolean">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued" disabled/>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-excel fileName="Products.xlsx" [fetchData]="allData"></kendo-grid-excel>
    </kendo-grid>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
    public state: State = {
        skip: 0,
        take: 5,
    };

    public gridData: GridDataResult = process(sampleProducts, this.state);

    public dataStateChange(state: DataStateChangeEvent): void {
        this.state = state;
        this.gridData = process(sampleProducts, this.state);
    }

    constructor() {
        this.allData = this.allData.bind(this);
    }

    public allData(): ExcelExportData {
        var myState : State = this.state;
        myState.skip = 0;
        myState.take = this.gridData.total;
        const result: ExcelExportData =  {
            data: process(sampleProducts, this.state).data
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marissa I have found the solution and it's the same as yours with the only slight difference is that I saved my current State.take (const currentTake = this.state.take;) then I passed my total records (this.state.take = this.gridData.total;) and before returning the result I returned the previous page size (this.state.take = currentTake;).